# The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to cretae a new Android App project Android 5.1.1 (API22). When I create a new project Web View App another project also created appcompact_v7

I got following error:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library
>   'C:\NewAndroidApps\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar' WebViewApp      Build
>   path  Build Path Problem

I have cleaned project appcompact_v7, I think that should crated appcompact_v7.jar file But I dont see that happening.

[image]

This project is created using Android 5.1.1 (API22), I googled it and most of the solution is moving to API21 or above. But in my case I'm already using API 22.

Here is my SDK Manager:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried update/install Android Support Library (you will find it in bottom of SDK list)

Comment: yes, Android support Library installed already